# Samba restart vs mount.cifs

Tags: samba, linux-networking, network-share

My question is more about ensuring rather than an exact problem.

I have a samba server (4.1) and I have a Linux client, which connects using this mount command:

```
mount.cifs $SHARE $DIR -o username=$USERNAME,password=$PASSWORD,domain=$DOMAIN
```

If I restart the samba service with

```
$ /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

The mounted filesystem is still usable.

Does mount.cifs reconnect if the mounted filesystem if the connection is lost? Is it okay, if I leave it without a monitoring system to remount the share?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am also using some cifs mounts on our systems and we recently got some networking issues in our company, I can say that it does reconnect. Otherwise all my shares and systems wouldn't work anymore.

Maybe others experienced other behaviour, but my shares always reconnected.

Comment: Confirm - reconnect feature works fine.